# What is the ASP.NET 5 equivalent of HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I think it is `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider` but when I use its `GetFileInfo(path)`, it doesn't find paths like `~\Images\foo.jpg`.  But the old API - `HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.FileExists(path)` - would find a path starting with `~\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trim the leading ~. MVC does this when it calls into the hosting environment, so coding with MVC apis makes it feel like ~/ is still supported to keep back compat working.

The core API though has no notion of ~/

See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/bd03142daba3854ac976906588bcaa1dc98accd0/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ActionResults/FilePathResult.cs#L151